# Not hard code end point in Apex callout

Tags: apex, webservices, callout, soap

I am using named credentials to store the username password for apex callout. In my apex class. I am storing using the below code to use the named credentials. Is there way not to hard code `some_path` URL in the code? Link - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206791&language=en_US&type=1

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: I suppose that if your named credential define the whole url, you don't need to add the '/some_path' at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I often use a **`Custom Label`** to make string values configurable in my code:

```
req.setEndpoint(Label.My_Credential_Name);
```

You can also always go to `Custom Settings` when you want to make parts of your `Apex` code configurable:

- **`List Custom Setting`**

  ```
  MySetting__c myCredential = MySetting__c.getInstance('Some Name');
  req.setEndpoint(myCredential.Path__c);
  ```
- **`Hierarchy Custom Setting`**

  ```
  req.setEndpoint(MySetting__c.getOrgDefaults().My_Credential_Name__c);
  ```

You might also consider `Custom Metadata Types`, which would operate similarly to the `List Custom Setting` approach.

Comment: I would never use custom label .Never for endpoints .Incase organizations translate they can translate these and would create huge issues later

Comment: Yes, translation would be problematic with labels. It seems like a bit of an admin training issue, though. I considered mentioning it but didn't find a way to concisely do so.

Comment: i've moved to Custom Metadata Types and away from list custom settings for the simple reason I get page layouts and hence easier to organize the various config fields